# Exchange 2010: PowerShell failure

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010

During a recent update, a novice sysadmin accidently cancelled an exchange update in the middle of the update.

The issue seems to be that PowerShell's webservice is not responding correctly. I checked the folder, and there is nothing there, except a web.config file.

Can anyone tell me what files are in their `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\ClientAccess\PowerShell` folder?

Answer (score 1):

The web.config file is the only one that should be there. If I were you, I'd try re-installing the Update Rollup that was cancelled...Usually they are really good about being reinstallable.

Answer (score 0):

Also see http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2010/12/07/457139.aspx (Resolving WinRM errors and Exchange 2010 Management tools startup failures).